# Replicate data by number of months - SQL Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql, consecutive-months

I need help from the community, I have a table that has the following information:

| Date | Number of Months | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | 1 | 7 |
| 2019-01-01 | 3 | 5 |
| 2019-02-01 | 2 | 9 |

Depending on the number of months, I need to replicate this for the following months and have an output like this:

| Date | Number of Months | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | 1 | 7 |
| 2019-01-01 | 3 | 5 |
| 2019-02-01 | 3 | 5 |
| 2019-03-01 | 3 | 5 |
| 2019-02-01 | 2 | 9 |
| 2019-03-01 | 2 | 9 |

How can I achieve this with SQL on Teradata?

Comment: What is the source of the date `2019-03-01` in the output?  This date is not in the input.

Comment: Exactly, this must be generated from the input, for example, if the input is 2019-01-01 and the number of months is 3, I need my output to be:
2019-01-01
2019-02-01
2019-03-01
I hope I was able to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Teradata's `EXPAND ON` syntax:

```
create volatile table mytable (TheDate date , NbrMonths smallint , _Value integer) 
no primary index on commit preserve rows;
insert mytable values(date'2019-01-01',1,7);
insert mytable values(date'2019-01-01',3,5);
insert mytable values(date'2019-02-01',2,9);

select begin(pd) as TheDate, NbrMonths, _Value
from mytable
expand on period (TheDate, (TheDate+interval '1' month * NbrMonths)) pd
by anchor month_begin;
```